# Excel VBA - I Have Too Many Cells To Be Considered A Range

Tags: excel, vba, range

I think my question is very different from a suggested "similar question", not least I have no interest in hidden rows, but this type of content makes it excruciatingly difficult to identify similar issues and solutions. I now have a difficulty in that if I am to try and create a union from breaking up my original string then is it possible to have an array in the union statement? If so how do you write this in the Union statement? I suspect that one cannot, so I now need another way to do this.

I am hoping someone can help! My issue is that I am trying to make a range, but have too many cells. (I understand that a range is limited to 255 characters.) As a result, I am getting an error "Run Time Error 1004 Method Range of object Global failed"!

My string is stored in a variable such as

`questionString(1) ="N5:AO6,... ,AB59" 'the actual string is much longer`

I am then trying to set a range using the contents of my string and go through each cell using a for each.

```
Dim cell as Range
Set rngF = Range(questionString(1)) 'The program crashes here

For Each cell In rngF
   'my code
Next cell
```

I note the code works fine if the string being processed is shorter.

I would be grateful if someone could suggest what I should do to get the code working!

Thank you for any guidance!

Comment: Use an array of strings, one for each group of cells, then loop through that?

Comment: Or use `Union`. Or use `Split` on `questionString(1)` and another loop. Though, how exactly is `questionString(1)` derived?

Comment: So the obvious solution is to take my string, break it into lengths of 255 characters and then join it as a union.

Comment: This issue caused me considerable problems and I only posted because I was finding it very difficult to solve my issue. I used the string functions to break down by code and then process it into blocks. However, I now realise this was a terrible decision and has made my code even more complicated!

Comment: The quickest solution by far would have been to use a split. I copy the key example code below

Comment: Dim ApplyRng As Range, z As Long, ApplyRngArr
If Not ApplyRng Is Nothing Then Set ApplyRng = Nothing
splitApplyRngArr = Split(stringtobeInserted, ",")

For z = 0 To UBound(ApplyRngArr)
   If ApplyRng Is Nothing Then
      Set ApplyRng = Range(ApplyRngArr(z))
   Else
   Set ApplyRng = Union(ApplyRng, Range(ApplyRngArr(z)))
End If

Next z